# How to accept either lower or capital case input in python loop?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Newbie here, just wanted to ask how can I use either lower or capital letter in my Python test?

let say, wether I input lower or capital letter in my pre defined condition it should be accepted.  ex. 'Y' or 'y'

Your insights will be appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Sample code:

```
students = []
reply = 'Y'

while reply == 'Y'
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    students.append(name)
    reply = input('Do you want to add another student name (Y/N)? ')
    if reply == 'Y':
        continue
    else:
        print('Student List updated...')
        break
see_output = input('Do you want to see the updated list Y/N?')
if see_output == 'Y':
    for names in students:
        print(names)
else:
    print('Ok.. Have a nice day')
```